# GeckoFX browser: Call C# function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko, geckofx

I'm trying to call the MessageBox.Show(p) function on the data (p) that I got from the MessageEvent of the GeckoWebBrowser. It's not working! Help?
(This should show a MessageBox saying "test")

Javascript:

```
function callServerFunction(fname, parameter) {
    event = new MessageEvent(fname, { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': parameter });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function fillClientsTable() {
    callServerFunction("fillClientsTable", "test");
}

window.onload = function () {
    fillClientsTable();
};
```

C#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    browser.AddMessageEventListener("fillClientsTable", (string p) => MessageBox.Show(p));
}
```

P.S. When tested, the functions onload(), fillClientsTable() and callServerFunction() are all called! (I checked using alert('test') inside each.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, turned out Form1_Load was not being called! Not sure why, but I removed it and re-added from the events list.
Now everything works :)